# ZXing C# Turn Flash on and off all permission set

Tags: c#, xaml, binding

This question has been asked in several different ways I have researched them all. I have a zxing xaml which can turn on flashlight without binding I have added binding but not sure I am binding it correctly as binding doesn't do it. Here is the code for ScanPage xaml

```
''''
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:VisiPageMain="clr-namespace:TechTracker.View" xmlns:zxing="clr-namespace:ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms;assembly=ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         x:Class="TechTracker.View.ScannerView">
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>

        <Grid VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">

            <zxing:ZXingScannerView x:Name="scanView"
                                    x:FieldModifier="public"
                                    IsTorchOn="{Binding TurnFlashOn, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                    IsScanning="true"
                                    IsAnalyzing="true"
                                    OnScanResult="scanView_OnScanResult"
                                    WidthRequest="700"
                                    HeightRequest="900"
                                    VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                    HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />

            <zxing:ZXingDefaultOverlay  TopText="Technician Tracker QR Custom Code Reader Software" BottomText="Align the barcode within the frame" />

        </Grid>

        <Grid Background="Blue">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Button Background="Gray" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="ButtonCancel" Text="Cancel" Clicked="btnCancel_Clicked" TextColor="White" />
            <Button Background="Gray" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="ButtonTorch" Text="Flash On" Clicked="btnTorchOn_Clicked" TextColor="White" IsEnabled="True" />
            <Button Background="Gray" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" x:Name="ButtonTorchOff" Text="Flash off" Clicked="btnTorchOFF_Clicked" TextColor="White" IsEnabled="False"/>
        </Grid>

    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>

''''
```

In The above Code If I Change IsTorchOn Binding to IsTorchOn="True" the light does come on.

Binding code

```
'''
 public partial class ScannerView : ContentPage
{

    VisitViewModel visitViewModel;

    public ScannerView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        visitViewModel = new VisitViewModel();
        BindingContext = visitViewModel;
        //visitViewModel.TurnFlashOn = true;

    }

    private void scanView_OnScanResult(ZXing.Result result)
    {

    }

    private void btnCancel_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void btnTorchOn_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        visitViewModel.TurnLightOn = true;
        //Navigation.PushAsync(new ScannerView());
    }

    private void btnTorchOFF_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        visitViewModel.TurnLightOn = false;
       // Navigation.PushAsync(new ScannerView());
    }

'''
```

MainPage

```
 public class VisitViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;


    public VisitViewModel()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void InitializeComponent()
    {

    }

    private bool _TurnFlashOn;
    public bool TurnLightOn
    {
        get { return _TurnFlashOn; }
        set
        {
            _TurnFlashOn = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new 
            PropertyChangedEventArgs("TurnFlashOn"));
            
        }
    }
}
```

I get no errors but the light doesnt come on. Why would the light come on when set manually eg IsTorchOn="true" am I bindinng it properly?

Answer (score 0):

Well upon reviewing the code I realized my mistake posting it here for others. The binding was close but not correct.
In the Scanview Change

```
IsTorchOn="{Binding TurnFlashOn, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

to

```
IsTorchOn="{Binding TurnLightOn, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

and
the main page to

```
 private bool _TurnFlashOn;
    public bool TurnLightOn
    {
        get { return _TurnFlashOn; }
        set
        {
            _TurnFlashOn = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("TurnLightOn"));
            
        }
    }
```

Comment: The key here was TurnLightON in both places including in the  Property changed event "TurnLightOn"